# "No such file or directory" error message when running program

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I can navigate to the directory where the program resides, see it when I list the directory contents, and run it by using the tab auto-complete feature so I have not mis-spelled the name. There are no spaces in the name, the file permissions are fine.

My only guess is that the program is looking for another file it cannot find.  But I ran the same program on another machine after the same installation process, and it ran fine.  Any ideas?

If it helps, I'm trying to install odrive (odrive.com) to sync my cloud storage because Dropbox is going to stop working, but that is a different support call ...

Comment: Would re-installation be too stressful, that might help!

Comment: Run `strace [program name]` to see what file the program is trying to find.

Comment: `ldd [program name]` may be helpful as well (in the case that it's a missing shared library - the output will likely be easier to read than that of strace)

Comment: Probably your current directory is not in your $PATH: run it like `./program_name`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice.

strace was interesting but not helpful to me this time.

ldd provided the clue: the file was not the same file after all, and this one was not executable under Linux. How it got installed, I don't know, but I'm not going to worry about that right now.  The error message, in this instance, simply means the file you are trying to run is not an executable (even though the file permissions say it is ...) - not a helpful message in this case, in my view!

Anyway, I replace the file with the equivalent from another machine and everything starts working.